# how get the last week start date and end date based on date in current week ruby

Tags: ruby

how to get the last week start date and end date based on date in current week ruby (Monday - Sunday)

Example: if date is 04-feb-15, then result should be start_date = Monday(26-jan-1015) end_date =  Sunday(1-feb-15)

if date is 27-feb-15, , then result should be start_date = Monday(16-feb-1015) end_date = (22-feb-15)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the source of [ActiveSupport's DateAndTime::Calculations](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/activesupport/4.2.0/symbols/DateAndTime::Calculations). That module supports all the calculations you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
require 'date'
=> true

date = Date.today
=> #<Date: 2015-02-04 ((2457058j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

# date.wday return week day
end_date = date-date.wday
=> #<Date: 2015-02-01 ((2457055j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

start_date = date-date.wday-6
=> #<Date: 2015-01-26 ((2457049j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

For more operations you can refer this link [Ruby Doc.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)

Answer (score 4):

- First date of last week

  ```
   Date.today.last_week.beginning_of_week
  ```
- Last date of last week

  ```
   Date.today.last_week.at_end_of_week
  ```

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this way**

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'

monday = (Date.today.beginning_of_week.last_week)

sunday = (Date.today.beginning_of_week.last_week + 6)
```

More details on the ActiveSupport Date extensions: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date

Answer (score 0):

Use Date#wday that tells with day of the week is for a given Date and then subtract accordinglly:

```
require 'date'

date = Date.parse("15-02-04")
monday = date - (date.wday + 6) # 2015-01-26
sunday = date - date.wday # 2015-02-01

date = Date.parse("15-02-27")
monday = date - (date.wday + 6) # 2015-02-16
sunday = date - date.wday # 2015-02-22
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the below code, working fine.

```
monday = (Date.today.beginning_of_week - 7) # 2015-01-26
sunday = (Date.today.end_of_week - 7) # 2015-02-01
```

Comment: beginning_of_week is not working in `irb`. It will work with rails active support